# Changing language flag and text on click

Tags: php, html, css

Back again with a new question.

I'm still working on that projects website, and i'm kind of stuck with a simple option.

Im trying to show a language flag at the menu with the current language. Just the flag, no text (maybe we'll want that later though).

Right now, the menu works like this:

**user_box.php**

```
    <?php trace(__FILE__,'begin'); ?>
<div id="userbox">
  <ul id="account_more_menu">

    <?php if(isset($_userbox_projects) && is_array($_userbox_projects) && count($_userbox_projects)) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('dashboard', 'my_projects') ?>"><?php echo lang('my projects') ?></a>
      <ul>
<?php if (logged_user()->canManageProjects()) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('project', 'add') ?>"><?php echo lang('add project') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('project', 'copy') ?>"><?php echo lang('copy project') ?></a></li>
<?php } // if ?>
        <li><span><?php echo lang('projects') ?>:</span></li>
    <?php if(100 > count($_userbox_projects)) { ?>
        <?php foreach($_userbox_projects as $_userbox_project) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $_userbox_project->getOverviewUrl() ?>"><?php echo clean($_userbox_project->getName()) ?></a></li>
        <?php } // foreach ?>
<?php } else { ?>
        <?php foreach($_userbox_projects as $_userbox_project) { ?>
<?php $name = clean($_userbox_project->getName()) ?>
<?php $url = clean($_userbox_project->getOverviewUrl()) ?>
<?php $first = strtoupper(substr($name,0,1)); ?>
<?php if (!array_key_exists($index, $first)) $index[$first]=array(); ?>
<?php $index[$first][] = array($name, $url); ?>
        <?php } // foreach ?>
        <?php foreach($index as $first => $items) { ?>
<li><a href=#><?php echo $first ?></a><ul>
          <?php foreach($items as $item) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $item[1] ?>"><?php echo $item[0] ?></a></li>
          <?php } // foreach ?>
</ul></li>
        <?php } // foreach ?>
<?php } // if ?>
<?php
  // PLUGIN HOOK
  plugin_manager()->do_action('my_projects_dropdown');
  // PLUGIN HOOK
?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } // if ?>

<?php if (!is_null(active_project())) { ?>
<?php if (use_permitted(logged_user(), active_project(), 'tasks')) { ?>
<?php if (isset($_userbox_projects) && is_array($_userbox_projects) && count($_userbox_projects)) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('dashboard', 'my_tasks') ?>"><?php echo lang('my tasks') ?></a>
      <ul>
        <li><span><?php echo clean(active_project()->getName()) ?>:</span></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('project', 'overview') ?>"><?php echo lang('overview') ?></a></li>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('message', 'index') ?>"><?php echo lang('messages') ?></a></li>
<?php if (ProjectMessage::canAdd(logged_user(), active_project())) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('message', 'add') ?>"><?php echo lang('add message') ?></a></li>
<?php } // if ?>

        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('milestone', 'index') ?>"><?php echo lang('milestones') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('milestone', 'calendar') ?>"><?php echo lang('view calendar') ?></a></li>
<?php if (ProjectMilestone::canAdd(logged_user(), active_project())) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('milestone', 'add') ?>"><?php echo lang('add milestone') ?></a></li>
<?php } // if ?>
<?php
  // PLUGIN HOOK
  plugin_manager()->do_action('my_tasks_dropdown');
  // PLUGIN HOOK
?>
      </ul>
    </li> 
<?php } // if ?>
<?php } // if ?>
<?php } // if ?>

    <?php if(logged_user()->isAdministrator()) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration') ?>"><?php echo lang('administration') ?></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'company') ?>"><?php echo lang('company') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('company', 'edit') ?>"><?php echo lang('edit company') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo owner_company()->getAddContactUrl() ?>"><?php echo lang('add contact') ?></a></li>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'clients') ?>"><?php echo lang('clients') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('company', 'add_client') ?>"><?php echo lang('add client') ?></a></li>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'projects') ?>"><?php echo lang('projects') ?></a></li>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'configuration') ?>"><?php echo lang('configuration') ?></a></li>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'plugins') ?>"><?php echo lang('plugins') ?></a></li>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'tools') ?>"><?php echo lang('administration tools') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'tool_mass_mailer') ?>"><?php echo lang('administration tool name mass_mailer' ) ?></a></li>
        <li class="header"><a href="<?php echo get_url('administration', 'upgrade') ?>"><?php echo lang('upgrade') ?></a></li>
<?php
 // PLUGIN HOOK
  plugin_manager()->do_action('administration_dropdown');
  // PLUGIN HOOK
?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } // if ?>

    <li class="user"><a href="<?php echo logged_user()->getAccountUrl() ?>"><?php echo lang('view') . ' ' . clean($_userbox_user->getDisplayName()) ?></a>
      <ul>
        <li><span><?php echo lang('account') ?>:</span></li>
<?php  if (logged_user()->canUpdateProfile(logged_user())) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo logged_user()->getEditProfileUrl() ?>"><?php echo lang('update profile') ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo logged_user()->getEditPasswordUrl() ?>"><?php echo lang('change password') ?></a></li>
<?php  } // if ?>
<?php  if (logged_user()->canUpdatePermissions(logged_user())) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo logged_user()->getUpdatePermissionsUrl() ?>"><?php echo lang('update permissions') ?></a></li>
<?php  } // if ?>
<?php
  // PLUGIN HOOK
  plugin_manager()->do_action('my_account_dropdown');
  // PLUGIN HOOK
?>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href=#><img src="<?php echo image_url('icons/language.gif') ?>" /></a><ul>
        <li><span><?php echo lang('select language') ?>:</span></li>
<?php
$base_language = config_option('installation_base_language', 'en_us');
$languages = array( $base_language => $base_language );
include(ROOT . '/language/locales.php');
if ($handle = opendir(ROOT . '/language')) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      if (array_key_exists( $file, $locales)) {
        $languages[$file] = $locales[$file];
      }
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
foreach( $languages as $locale => $desc ) {
  echo '<li><a href="' . get_url('dashboard', 'index', array('language' => $locale) ) . '" >' . $desc . '</a></li>';
}
?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="logout" class="js-confirm" href="<?php echo get_url('access', 'logout') ?>" title="<?php echo lang('confirm logout') ?>"><?php echo lang('logout') ?></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php trace(__FILE__,'end'); ?>
```

As you can see it just shows a single image. And i can't seem to figure out how to change this to adjust to the language.

I usually end up with these results:

[image: result NL]

[image: result EN]

In the language file the menu options are showed, and you can change these. So i changed them using a sprite with a flag.

[image]

**Sprite language menu option (locales.php):**

```
<?php

$locales = array(
  'bg_bg' => 'Bulgarian (Bulgaria)',
  'cz_cz' => 'Czech',
  'da_dk' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-dk" alt="Danish" /> Danish',
  'de_de' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-de" alt="German" /> German',
  'el_gr' => 'Greek',
  'en_us' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-gb" alt="English" /> English',
  'es_ar' => 'Spanish (Argentina)',
  'es_es' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-es" alt="Spanish" /> Spanish',
  'es_mx' => 'Spanish (Mexico)',
  'fi_fi' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-fi" alt="Finnish" /> Finnish',
  'fr_fr' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-fi" alt="Finnish" /> Finnish',
  'hu_hu' => 'Hungarian (Hungary)',
  'hu_if' => 'Hungarian (informal)',
  'is_is' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-is" alt="Icelandic" /> Icelandic',
  'it_it' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-it" alt="Italian" /> Italian',
  'lt_lt' => 'Lithuanian (Lithuania)',
  'nl_nl' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-nl" alt="Dutch (Nederlands)" /> Dutch',
  'no_nb' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-no" alt="Norwegian" /> Norwegian',
  'pl_pl' => 'Polish (Poland)',
  'pt_br' => 'Portuguese (Brazil)',
  'pt_pt' => 'Portuguese (Portugal)',
  'ru_ru' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-ru" alt="Russian" /> Russian',
  'sl_si' => 'Slovenian (Slovenia)',
  'sv_se' => 'Swedish (sv_se)',
  'tr_tr' => 'Turkish (Turkey)',
  'vn_vn' => 'Vietnamese',
  'zh_cn' => '<img src="images/blank.gif" class="flag flag-cn" alt="Chinese" /> Simplified Chinese',
);

?>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flag {
    width: 16px;
    height: 11px;
    background:url(/images/flags.png) no-repeat
}

.flag.flag-cn {background-position: -16px 0}
.flag.flag-de {background-position: -32px 0}
.flag.flag-dk {background-position: -48px 0}
.flag.flag-es {background-position: 0 -11px}
.flag.flag-fi {background-position: -16px -11px}
.flag.flag-gb {background-position: -32px -11px}
.flag.flag-is {background-position: -48px -11px}
.flag.flag-it {background-position: 0 -22px}
.flag.flag-nl {background-position: -16px -22px}
.flag.flag-no {background-position: -32px -22px}
.flag.flag-ru {background-position: -48px -22px}
```

`

Now i have tried multiple things. But I can not seem to get the right code. Basically what I want is to change the icon (dutch flag in the images) to change to the correct language flag. It would be favoured to do this by using that sprite, but if that would be too much, I could just make seperate images. I just need some help figuring out this code to make it work.

Comment: Here : `<li><a href=#><img src="<?php echo image_url('icons/language.gif') ?>" /></a><ul>` I can't see any `.flag` class.

Comment: No that is correct. That's because I wasn't sure on how to implement the flag class there in such a way that it changes depending on the language chosen. PHP is not my strongest language.

Comment: Instead of the last picture the HTML would be really helpful. What link(s) produces this code `<a href="' . get_url('dashboard', 'index', array('language' => $locale) ) . '" >`?

Comment: I edited the post. Full menu code is in there now. All codes that should be necessary. That exact line seems to echo the list of menu items shown. When i remove it from the code, the menu also doesn't list anymore.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do that in this case. As you can see it pulls from multiple files.

Comment: Still no answers? :(